# Storing number of digits in to an array

Tags: c#

As a student i am very new to stack overflow and programming too,so I want to store the digits in a user input number or given in to an array.like `"54634"` to `int[]a={5,4,6,3,4}`.please anyone can help me

Comment: Your solution is just Just one single google-search away. Did it for you and wrote the exact duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Try *Linq*:

```
using System.Linq;
```

...

```
string source = "54634";

int[] result = source.Select(c => c - '0').ToArray();
```

If you want to include *user input*, you have to validate it (*Linq* once again):

```
string source = null;

// Keep on asking user to put number until input
//   1. Has at least one character - source.Any()
//   2. All characters age digits  - source.All(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9') 
do {
  Console.WriteLine("Please, input arbitrary non-negative integer number");
  source = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
}
while (!(source.Any() && source.All(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9')));

int[] result = source.Select(c => c - '0').ToArray();

...
```

Comment: Should we really answer the same old questions again and again and ...?

Answer (score 1):

Or with LINQ and `char.GetNumericValue`/`int.Parse`:

```
int[] digits = "54634".Select(c => (int)char.GetNumericValue(c)).ToArray();
// or 
int[] digits = "54634".Select(c => int.Parse(c.ToString())).ToArray();
```

The `int.Parse` isn't very efficient. I'd either use [Dmitry's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47453643/284240) approach or `char.GetNumericValue`.

Comment: An eerie input like `"1¼"` will return `{1, 0}` array (1st solution with `GetNumericValue`); sure, it's just an academic counter example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string numbers = "012345";
int[] res = numbers.Where(a => Char.IsNumber(a)).Select(c => Convert.ToInt32(c))).ToArray();
```